# How should I approach the circuit analysis of this reflexive receiver?

Tags: circuit-analysis, rf, bjt

I built the following circuit:

[image]
I got this circuit from this YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PojBHqtzlAI&t=13s).
It works well, although the volume is quite low. My main question is how would I approach circuit analysis of this circuit on paper. I have a basic understanding of DC and AC analysis of BJT circuits, but this one has me confused. Would someone be able to provide me with their step by step analysis of the circuit? As in how could I calculate the theoretical gain, input/output impedance, etc. Two sticking points for me are how would I treat L2 in DC analysis as it's an inductor but also the signal source. What about the base current of T2 and collector current of T1, I imagine the collector current of T1 is equal to I(R1)-I(T2 Base)? The circuits I am used to analyzing are separated by blocking capacitors so I can analyze each block, but these are all interconnected which is confusing me.

I want to have a better understanding of how it works on paper so I could modify it in the future.

Comment: Try looking up regenerative receivers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some "ideas" for simulating this circuit.
Not very "easy", but "accessible" ...

Note that I have changed the impedance of the headphones to 1 kOhm.

[image]

[image]

And finally, the "result":

[image]